# Write excel data in end of column in the Excel Sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to add value in the end of the column and but if i run the class it overrides the excel

JAVA , Apache POI:

```
    // Blank workbook
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    // Create a blank sheet
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("MyPolicies");
    // Iterate over data and write to sheet
    Set<Integer> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (Integer key : keyset) {
        // this creates a new row in the sheet
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr) {

            // this line creates a cell in the next column of that row
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            if (obj instanceof String) {
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            }

            else if (obj instanceof Integer)
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
        }
    }
    try {
        // this Writes the workbook
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("extract.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Excel overrides every time and new data alone is added.
Note : If both the ID's are same , we need to add the second map data in the same row

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you, so that the question may be resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your document is replaced every time is that your `workbook` is blank. `workbook.write(out)` means you write everything in the workbook to a location (extract.xlsx), not that you write the data of your workbook into a file!

What you should be doing is open the workbook you're trying to edit:

```
FileInputStream xlsFile = new FileInputStream("extract.xls");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(xlsFile);
```

... get the last row or column

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
```

... and write your data from there.
Then, as before, you can use `workbook.write(out)` to save your workbook.

Comment: FileInputStream xlsFile = new FileInputStream("extract.xls");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(myxls);
if (workbook.getSheet("MyPolicies") != null) {
sheet = workbook.getSheet("MyPolicies");
} else {
    sheet =  workbook.createSheet("MyPolicies");
}
//after that uodated the sheet in same excel,
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(xlsfile));
   workbook.write(out);

if i write that then the excel is not updating with new values

Comment: Second line should be xlsFile, not myxls. Try with that!